# Parameter from xml file to powershell command

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing, performancecounter

I would like to have with powershell some performance counters dynamically. To do that, the counters are written in xml file. The problem with this solution is the following :

This is my config file:

```
<root>
<performanceCounters>
    <performanceCounterName>"\ASP.NET Applications(*)\Requests in Application Queue"</performanceCounterName>
    <performanceCounterName>"\ASP.NET Applications(*)\Requests Executing"</performanceCounterName>
    <performanceCounterName>"\ASP.NET Applications(*)\Request Execution Time"</performanceCounterName>
    <performanceCounterName>"\ASP.NET Applications(*)\Pipeline Instance Count"</performanceCounterName>
</performanceCounters>
</root>
```

This is how I parse the file and then pass the parameter to the get-counter command :

```
[xml]$userfile = Get-Content .\file.xml    
$performanceCounters=$userfile.GetElementsByTagName("performanceCounterName")
For ($j=0; $j -lt $performanceCounters.Count; $j++) 
{
   $string= $performanceCounters.Item($j).innerText 
   Get-Counter $string
}
```

When I execute script, I get the following error for each 'Get-Counter':

```
Get-Counter : The specified counter path could not be interpreted.
At D:\tmon\agent\counters.ps1:18 char:13
+     Get-Counter <<<<  $string
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

This error is very strange, because when I define the parameter in my script file like this:

$string= "\ASP.NET Applications(*)\Requests in Application Queue"

And then, run 'Get-Counter $string', it works. I checked in the 2 methods, the parameter $string seems to be built in the same way and have the same type.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have double quotes (`"`) in your xml. Get rid of them and your script should work.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your quick and very efficient answer. I don't remember why I add the quotes. It works now.